# Saving message content to a list discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a playlist which the bot can send but I can't figure it out, here's the code I've tried although it only takes the text to trigger the command and I can't access the list anywhere.

Code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "=playlist":
        playlist = message.content
        await message.channel.send(playlist)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what the problem is, by the looks of it, when a users message is `=playlist`, your code will send all the contents of that message essentially back to them. Is that not what you want?